# Python Ordered Pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python, and I am trying to generate ordered pairs, and then evaluate the Domain and Range of the set relation. My issue with my current code is that it sets up the list just fine, but rather than giving me the actual ordered pair, it gives me (what I am assuming is) the address of the ordered pair.

```
    relation = [[] for i in range(numOrderPairs)]
    for x in range(numOrderPairs):
       inputOrderPair = input("\nPlease enter an ordered pair, i.e (x, y).")
       orderPair = (int(t.strip("(),")) for t in inputOrderPair.split())
       relation[x] = orderPair
    print(relation)

    >>>[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f4242a0ab48>, <generator object 
       <genexpr> at 0x7f4242a0aba0>, <generator object <genexpr> at 
       0x7f4242a0abf8>]
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code returns a generator.

```
(int(t.strip("(),")) for t in inputOrderPair.split())
```

I think you possibly expected it to create a tuple, in which case you would have to do something like this;

```
tuple(int(t.strip("(),")) for t in inputOrderPair.split())
```

Or you could just use a list instead

```
[int(t.strip("(),")) for t in inputOrderPair.split()]
```

Comment: Oh, wow. That simple, huh? Thanks so much! That was really stumping me.

Comment: Yep :) Generates are amazing - but they're also one-shot, so not what you probably want here.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler and safer way is to eval your expression, with `ast.literal_eval` :

Exemple :

```
In [70]: inputOrderPair='(2,4)'

In [71]: ast.literal_eval(inputOrderPair)
Out[71]: (2, 4)
```